# When can't I update my files on theme editor of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, visual-web-developer

When I went to Appearance on dashboard and then clicked on theme editor to update some files. However, when I tried to click 'update'. The error message

"Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP." shows up.

I have tested every single plug-in. But, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the plug-in. The theme was built by a previous developer hired before me. So, could it possibly have something to do with the ownership or permission set by the previous programmer. If so, am I still able to upload the file over FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Message comes from Wordpress, This option disabled by WordPress for preventing down the site because if who somebody edited themes while had a syntax error after saving code then he/she can not be edit codes again. So, he/she must resolve this issue with Host panel (cPanel or etc).

If you want to enable this option you can use below code in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false );
```

The best practice for edit themes is Git or FTP.

Comment: The site was built on WordPress, but hosted by Inmotion. If I need to do it with FTP on FileZilla. Do I need to connect to WordPress or Inmotion on Filzilla?

Comment: you must have an FTP connection from Inmotion, then goto root of Wordpress and edit wp-config.